# $\dfrac{d}{d\beta}\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i)^\beta\bigg)$ Taking the derivative of a summation raised to a power

Tags: calculus, statistics, derivatives, summation

This came up as part of a problem in my undergrad stats class.

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{d}{d\beta}\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i)^\beta\bigg)
\end{equation}

I'm of the mindset that $\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i)^\beta ln(x_i) $ is not the solution. Can someone shed some light on this for me. Thanks

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: What is the question? "Can ..." ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [sum rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_rule_in_differentiation), we can write\begin{equation}
\dfrac{d}{d\beta}\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^\beta\bigg)
=\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac{d}{d\beta}x_i^\beta\bigg)=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^\beta \ln(x_i)\end{equation}
From the [derivative of a exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_rules#Derivatives_of_exponential_and_logarithmic_functions). So, sorry, but you're mindset is incorrect. For further intuition, think of the [linearity of differentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity_of_differentiation). That would probably make things simpler.

Comment: just wanted to make sure. I was looking at a derivation online and it included $e^{ln\beta}$ to what you have above. Thanks